# How to apply a function to several variables in R?

Tags: r, string, function, lapply

I have a simple/confusing question in R.

Here is an example of my problem.

I have a string of numbers or characters:

```
data <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

and I have a function which I want to apply to several variables in the string.

```
dd <- function(d){if(d==data[1:3]) 'yes'
else 'no'}
```

but when I apply the function to the string I got this error

```
unlist(lapply(data,dd))
```

Warning message:

```
   1: In if (d == data[1:3]) "yes" :
    the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
    2: In if (d == data[1:3]) "yes" :
    the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
    3: In if (d == data[1:3]) "yes" :
    the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
   4: In if (d == data[1:3]) "yes" :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
   5: In if (d == data[1:3]) "yes" :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

So, My question is how can I apply the function to several variables in the string not just for the first element?
to get an output like

```
"yes" "yes" "yes" "no" "no"
```

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: No need for a `lapply` loop: `ifelse(d %in% data[1:3], "yes", "no")`

Comment: It works but how can I apply this to for example:

if I want to have 'yes' for c(1,2) and 'no' for '3' and 'None' to the rest (4,5)?
is there any other way to combine these three conditions in ifelse?

as far as I know it's only possible to define 2conditions to ifelse(like yes/no)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a `lapply` loop. You can use the vectorized `ifelse` and need to use `%in%`: `ifelse(d %in% data[1:3], "yes", "no")`

Answering the follow-up question in your comment:

> It works but how can I apply this to for example: if I want to have 'yes' for c(1,2) and 'no' for '3' and 'None' to the rest (4,5)?

There are several ways to achieve that. You could use a nested `ifelse`. However, in the specific example I would use `cut`:

```
cut(data, breaks = c(-Inf, 2, 3, Inf), labels = c("yes", "no", "None"))
#[1] yes  yes  no   None None
#Levels: yes no None
```

Comment: I found the other way by using nested ifelse !
thanks for your help Roland! :)